# When can we use integral to calculate totals of a histogram values

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, definite-integrals, binomial-distribution

I am confused about something relating to histograms.
A histogram is a visual tool to display the distribution of numerical data.
One example is when we have the binomial distribution of a set of successes of spinning a coin:
[image]

Taking into account that the width of a bar in the histogram is 1 the use of the integral is used to show the probability that e.g. we get from 2 up to 5 heads
i.e. 
$\int_{2}^{5}y_{x} dx$ where x is the number of heads.

Question: Is it because we can derive a curve that goes through all the midpoints of the top of each bar and we can use the integral approach or is that irrelevant?
So basically I am confused as to whether we can sum the values that each bar represent to get the value in that range or the histogram must describe an area that a graph covers

So if we have an histogram that is completely asymetric e.g.
[image]

that does not seem that we know of a formula for a graph that matches the boundaries of the histogram can we still use a summation of the histogram bars to get the value for that range of values?

Answer (score 1):

For the first histogram it is exactly the CLT (or Laplace-De Moivre) theorem. You can see the full proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem), however the bottom line is that your original Binomial r.v can be approximated by the Normal distribution for large enough $n$, namely if you have $Bin(n,p)$ thus 
$$
P(X=k) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n p q}}\exp\{-\frac{(k-np)^2}{2npq}\}.
$$
So you can use integration to calculate the approximate approximate the probability of any number of success, in particular 
$$
P(2\le X\le 5)\approx \int_{2}^5 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n p q}}\exp\{-\frac{(k-np)^2}{2npq}\}\mathrm{d}k .
$$

Comment: So in order to use integration the histogram should approximate a graph? So the second example can not use integration if there is no graph matching it?

Comment: You can, but you have the find the proper continuous distribution that approximates it (or maybe a mixture of random variables).

Comment: So if there is no such approximation then we can't use integration, right?

Comment: Yes, but I think you can always find some continuous approximation to a discrete random variable, the only question is how good and general this approximation is. The CLT of the first case is basically a (weak) convergence of the Binomial random variable, thus this approximation is "natural". So if you constrain yourself to that kind of approximations then sure there will be discrete distributions without "decent" continuous approximation (namely, you will not be able to use integration).

Comment: This is the part that is confusing to me. Let's take the second histogram-image of the post. That seems that there is no relevant matching graph and let's also assume this as well. The width of a bar of a histogram is 1 so that $\delta x = 1$. So what is the error when summing the individual values of each bar? What is it that we are over-calculating? (I am not sure if I made clear my question on what I am confused about)

Comment: Let me see if I understand right your question. You have data which you can visualize with a histogram. You know nothing about the process that have generated it and you are wondering whether calculating the area of some specified bars will give you a good estimate of the corresponding  probability (e.g., $P(2\le X \le 5)$). Is it right?

Comment: Exactly making also the assumption that $\sum_{i=a}^{b}y dx = \int_a^b y dx$

Comment: 1. If You can assume at least finite second moment and you have large enough $n$, then generally it should be OK. 
2. Without any further information this integration is very shaky approximation.